# How can I attach a file to an MMS message?

Tags: sms, files, file-transfer, mms, attachments

Can I attach files to an MMS message? I am looking for a way to attach files like doc, pdf, or zip and send them over MMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular android messaging apps tend to disallow files other than image/video.

I use [Tmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phonelight.tmailtrial) by Phonelight available from Google Play Store:

> Tmail breaks the restrictions of all the Messaging apps. It is the only app that allows the user to attach any kind of file to an MMS message. You are now not limited to image, audio or video file. Tmail has expanded the MMS capability.

[image: Tmail message example with pdf attachment]

You can use the trial version to test it. the unlimited version costs 0,81€.

Comment: Does the recipient also need this software installed? Or will the file(s) be transferred without any additional software?

Comment: @Sparx This software isn't necessary to receive the files. Some devices may append `.jpg` at the end of the file name, but that's easily solved with a rename after the download.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be available on playstore now

Comment: Google it, have to look a bit... Tmail was removed from the Play Store almost 4 years ago. Flagging your answer for deletion, since it is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Tmail has been removed from the Play Store, so the link no longer works.

Comment: The app indeed was unpublished in 2015. But checking [its record at Appbrain](https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.phonelight.tmailtrial), you can find alternatives easily – e.g. [Magic Text](https://www.appbrain.com/app/magic-text/com.pompeiicity.magictext) :)